# Array indexOf and filter implementation for IE giving other Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following impletations

```
if (!('forEach' in Array.prototype)) {
            Array.prototype.forEach= function(action, that /*opt*/) {
                for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                    if (i in this)
                        action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
            };
        }

        if (!('filter' in Array.prototype)) {
            Array.prototype.filter= function(filter, that /*opt*/) {
                var other= [], v;
                for (var i=0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                    if (i in this && filter.call(that, v= this[i], i, this))
                        other.push(v);
                return other;
            };


        }
```

but when i am using a for loop for ex its acting kind of weird

```
var conditionJSONObject=new Array();
var conditionCombiner=new Array();
var combiner ;
combiner = jQuery.trim(jQuery(conditionTable.rows[i+1].cells[4].children[0]).select().val());
for(var index in conditionJSONObject)
{               
    if(conditionCombiner[index].combiner.toUpperCase() == 'AND')
    {/*Some code of mine*/}
}
```

this code gives error though initially it was working fine also same code works fine on FF.when i inspected index value was 'ForEach' ... is it something because of using prototype??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach = ...` does add a `forEach` property to all arrays. You can avoid it in `for(.. in ..)` loops like this:

```
for(var index in array) {
    if(!array.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
    ...//loop body
}
```

Or you can also use it as indented like this:

```
array.forEach(function(value,index) {
    ...//loop body
});
```

Comment: ur first solution is gud but for this i need to do changes in numerous for loop that my page has ... so c if u can provide some generic/one point change sol .. and ur second sol i cant use as it has issues on IE thats why i used implementations in the first place..

Comment: I don't know a way to add stuff to Array.prototype and not break the native `for(..in..)` loops (at least in IE8 and earlier). The purpose of your additional implementations are to allow `array.forEach(...)` and `array.filter(...)` if you don't need to use those you can remove them.

Comment: even after using `if(array.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;` in my for loop i am getting the same issue .. :(

Comment: Oops.. there should be a `!` there... fixed it.